# Cannot catch orientation changes from "upsidedown" to landscapes on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation

I need to invalidate my collection view layout when screen orientation changes. Since iPhone X and others have safe area insets; I need my cells' subviews positioned according to screen safe area insets.

If you switch between left-right landscapes from portrait there is no problem. But if you switch from upsidedown I cannot catch the orientation change and automatically cannot

I tried two existing approaches.

First is using `NotificationCenter`. Second is overriding `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` function. It's all the same.

in CollectionViewController:

```swift
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notif) in
      self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

in Cell:

```swift
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    if let insets = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets {
      if orientation == .landscapeLeft {
        titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = insets.left + 20
        titleLabelTrailingConstraint.constant = 20
      } else if orientation == .landscapeRight {
        titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = 20
        titleLabelTrailingConstraint.constant = insets.right + 20
      } else {
        titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = 20
        titleLabelTrailingConstraint.constant = 20
      }
    }

    print("orin: \(orientation.rawValue) | left: \(titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant) | right: \(titleLabelTrailingConstraint.constant)")

  }
```

The `print()` function not being called when you switch from/to upsidedown. But `collectionviewlayout`s `invalidateLayout()` function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already tried, you can detect orientation change using `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`.

I don't know your first attempt, however, try this:

```
      override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
         //If you need to invalidate your collectionView layout, do it in this function
         super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
         if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
          //
         } else {
           //
         }
      }
```

If you need to know the difference between landscapeLeft or Right, try your code in this way:

```
      override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
         //If you need to invalidate your collectionView layout, do it in this function
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

     if let insets = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft {

        titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = insets.left + 20
        titleLabelTrailingConstraint.constant = 20

      } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {

        titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = 20
        titleLabelTrailingConstraint.constant = insets.right + 20

      } else {

        titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = 20
        titleLabelTrailingConstraint.constant = 20

      }
    }
  }
```

> ***NOTE:*** You don't need to register an observer

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that since an `UICollectionViewCell` does not have  `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`. On the other hand, the collection view does not know about its cells. So it cannot update cell constraints.

Basically, it's all about cells and its descendants, not the controller.

Comment: Well, I misunderstood the problem. Try to override `layoutIfNeeded` and then trigger `cell.layoutIfNeeded` on layout changes

Comment: Using `layoutIfNeeded()` gives the same result. Now I tried observing orientation changes **from the cell**. It's working. But that much registration is a wise thing; I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

OK. At last, I came up with the thing I did not want to do. Observed orientation changes from the cells' themselves.

```swift
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notif ) in
      // doing my things already stated in the question's itself.
    }
  }
```

Now they can observe all the changes. But I do not know if this much registration is a wise thing; even though collection view reuses cells and -in my case- 7 to 8 cells are on screen at most.

Comment: I suggest you cleanup that observer on deinit. Otherwise, you are leaking observations